# How the word 'Windows' is related with the term 'Windows Communication Foundation?

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf

I am beginner in the Windows Communication Foundation. I am reading about it. I am little bit confused with the word 'Windows'. WCF can be used for building the web services for window application as well as web application. Then what is meaning of the word 'Windows' in WCF ? Why we are calling it as a 'Windows' Communication foundation ? Please explain in detail with example.

Comment: Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is Microsoft's unified programming model for building service-oriented applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means that the web services itself is running on **Windows technology stack** (Windows Server, IIS, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This is all marketing, I believe. Or how else is it possible to come up with something like *"Windows Azure AppFabric Service Bus"* or *"Microsoft Windows Vista Ultimate Upgrade Limited Numbered Signature Edition"*?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to think of that instance of the word Windows as in *runs on Microsoft Windows* rather than that it's a *Windows Forms* related technology.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because underlying OS will always be some or other Windows flavor.

Comment: Unless it is running on Mono, in which case it will be Linux.

Comment: Oh well. Didn't know it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

Long time ago, before everyone switched to Linux and FreeBSD, there used to be operating system named Windows, written by Microsoft. Hardly anybody now remembers that product, but it's name is still used in some technologies originating from that operating system, such as Windows Communication Foundation;)